# Error in data Binding in Android

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

activity_main.xml

```
<data class="LoginDataBinding">

    <variable
        name="login"
        type="com.example.itstym.logina.LoginViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="ModelClickListener"
        type="com.example.itstym.logina.interface.ClickListener" />

</data>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome, Back"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

    <EditText
        app:error="@{login.errorEmail}"
        android:hint="@{login.emailHint}"
        android:text="@{login.userEmailAddress}"
        android:id="@+id/user_email_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        app:error="@{login.errorPassword}"
        android:text="@{login.userPassword}"
        android:hint="@{login.passwordHint}"
        android:id="@+id/user_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_email_address"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="@{(v)->ModelClickListener.onSubmitButtonClick()}"
        android:text="@{login.loginButtonText}"
        android:id="@+id/login_submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final LoginDataBinding loginDataBinding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

        LoginViewModel viewModel = new LoginViewModel("Enter Email Address","Enter password","Login");

        loginDataBinding.setLogin(viewModel);

        loginDataBinding.setModelClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loginDataBinding.getLogin().getUserEmailAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loginDataBinding.getLogin().getUserPassword(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error unresolved reference for `setModelClickListener()` but the setLogin() works perfertly normal. 
One more thing why the `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);` return the LoginDataBinding instead of MainActivityBinding?

Comment: because you are using `<data class=...`?

Comment: @pskink even I remove that. It is returning the LoginDataBinding. Moreover,  studio says unknown attribute when points to class attribute of data tag.

Comment: then clean up everything and try again

Comment: I have created the new project and tried in that also but same error @pskink

Comment: Nops it is not there. even MainActivityBinding is also not working. @pskink

Comment: nops. now I don't know the return type. neither it is LoginDataBinding or MainActivityBinding.

Comment: thanks @pskink. it return package_name.databinding.ActivityMainBinding. When I add the same return type. it works perfectly.

Comment: hey @pskink is there any bug in stackoverflow?. Your comment is deleted after certain time.